# stargazer error: Error: Unrecognized object type

Tags: r, stargazer

I ran these regressions for a school assignment:
#linear regression model:
summary(agg_lm2 <- lm(formula = civilian_fatalities ~ conflict_intensity + wdi_primhc + military_quality, data = merge_agg2))

#A linear regression model where you have log-transformed the dependent variable (got_cwyr_dummy) (Hint: we have zeroes in our DV so we have to add one, or use the `log1p()` function to do this transformation)
summary(agg_lm_dummy2 <- lm(formula = civilian_deaths_dummy ~ conflict_intensity + wdi_primhc + military_quality, data = got_mergeagg_dummy))

#A Poisson regression model
summary(agggot_glm.p2 <- glm(civilian_fatalities ~ conflict_intensity + wdi_primhc + military_quality, family="poisson", data = merge_agg2))

#A negative binomial regression model
summary(agggot_glm.nl2 <- MASS::glm.nb(civilian_fatalities ~ conflict_intensity + wdi_primhc + military_quality, data = merge_agg2))

#A logistic regression model where you use the dummy variable you created in exercise 1.5 as the dependent variable
summary(agggot_glm.log2 <- glm(civilian_deaths_dummy ~ conflict_intensity + wdi_primhc + military_quality, family = "binomial", data = got_mergeagg_dummy))

then I wanted to summarize them by using stargazer:
stargazer(agg_lm2, agg_lm_dummy2, agggot_glm.p2, agggot_glm.nl2, agggot_glm.log2, title = "Regression Results", type = "text")

However it gives an error: Error: Unrecognized object type.

I however managed to run this stargazer code before. I just deleted my global environment and reran all my code, and all of a sudden stargazer does not work anymore.

I tried:
stargazer(agg_lm2, agg_lm_dummy2, agggot_glm.p2, agggot_glm.nl2, agggot_glm.log2, title = "Regression Results", type = "text")

And I expected the stargazer table for these models to appear but I got an error: Error: Unrecognized object type.

Comment: [‘stargazer’ is a terrible package.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/comment/dkgw9q1/) I strongly recommend against using it. Use anything else instead, e.g. ‘[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’.